# Embedded Jetty loading wrong project in acceptance test

Tags: scala, sbt, lift, embedded-jetty

I have a project with several `sbt` submodules:

```
Project
|
+--- acceptance
+--- dmz
+--- back-end
```

Both *dmz* and *back-end* are Lift projects. *Dmz* has a full UI, *back-end* contains Rest calls. *Acceptance* has acceptance tests (using Selenium and ScalaTest) for the project.

**SET UP**

When running the tests the first thing the suite does is to start 2 embedded jetty servers for the projects using the following code:

```scala
val dmzWarPath = "dmz/target/scala-2.11/classes/webapp"
val backendWarPath = "back-end/src/main/webapp"    

def startDmz() = startServer(10280, "/dmz", dmzWarPath)    
def startInternal() = startServer(10400, "/back-end", backendWarPath)

def startServer(port: Int, contextPath: String, warPath: String): Unit = {    
   val server = new Server(port)

   val context = new WebAppContext()
   context.setContextPath(contextPath)
   context.setServer(server)
   context.setWar(warPath)

   server.setHandler(context)
   server.setStopAtShutdown(true)

   server.start()
}

startDmz()
startInternal()
```

**ISSUE**

Embedded Jetty seems to be loading the first project it finds in the classpath, whatever context I set. If I comment all the code related to load *Dmz* and run the tests while trying to load *back-end*, *Dmz* will be loaded instead if it appears first in the classpath.

I can reproduce this classpath ordering issue in IntelliJ by modifying the classpath in the test launcher so I'm quite confident this is the issue.

Yes, I've run sbt clean, recompiled, even restarted laptop.

Any idea on how to fix this issue? How can I force Jetty to ignore classpath and load the wars I'm providing instead?

**TO CLARIFY**

As far as I can see I'm pointing Jetty to a path (back-end/src/main/webapp) but it is ignoring that and loading instead the first project it finds in the classpath.

I need to understand why is it ignoring the path I set via context.

I need to understand why is it automatically loading things from classpath without anyone asking.

Comment: Why 2 servers?  Why not just 1 server (with 2 connectors and 2 webapps)?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt should it matter? If it's loading the first project in the classpath I may still have 2 contexts serving the same code. In any case, even if it can be optimised, why is this not working? Why is it loading the first project in classpath?

Comment: You have a build environment with all of the classpath baggage, and then you create 2 instances of the Server object each with its own classpath baggage, then you create a WebAppContext each, also with its classpath baggage. (3 levels deep now).   Go ahead and set `Server.setDumpAfterStart(true)` and check out the various classpath/classloader entries.

Comment: Also, where's your `Server.start()` call?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt added the server.start. I've done the DumpAfterStart, that is why I know that the order in the classloader matters. Please read my clarification above as we are deviating from the issue